# Undefined name 'Firestore' Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore:
```

I config it properly please help

Comment: place cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 and cloud_firestore: in different lines in you pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: yes its in differline

Comment: http://prntscr.com/yht7vf

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem you're having? is there a specific error message that you're getting?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/yhu78y

I want to search firestore using single query its showing

The method 'getDocuments' isn't defined for the type 'Query'.

Any help ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no class named `Firestore`. Use `FirebaseFirestore.instance` instead.

example:

```dart
var snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat')
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots();
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the name from 'Firestore' to 'FirebaseFirestore'.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

Install Dependencies :-

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3
  firebase_core: ^0.5.2
```

Import Package :-

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

Access Firestore :-

```
Future getMembers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("Members").get();
    final documents = querySnapshot.docs;
    return documents
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this pubspec.yaml

```html
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
```